# Logical error: Cleaning the phone number in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, data-cleaning

I want to create a function to check phone numbers in list format. The function will perform cleaning according to the following criteria:

- Starts with 62, e.g. 62xxxxxxxxxxx
- It must be an 11-digit number, excluding 62
- After cleaning, if there is an invalid phone number, change the phone number to 'Invalid number'

Here the code

```
def clean_phone_number(phone_lists):
    
    phone_clean = []
    
    for phone in phone_lists:
        # Remove all non-digit characters
        cleaned_number = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, phone))
        
        # Check if the cleaned number starts with '62' and has 11 digits
        if len(cleaned_number) == 11 and cleaned_number.startswith('62'):
            phone_clean.append(int('62' + cleaned_number))  # Convert to integer and add '62' prefix
        else:
            phone_clean.append('Invalid number')
    
    return phone_clean

phone_lists = [
    '82123321123',
    '082321123321',
    '+6282-456-654-456',
    '+62 82 789 987 789',
    '14045',
    '82145-451-145'
]

phone_clean = clean_phone_number(phone_lists)
print(phone_clean)
```

and here the output

```
['Invalid number', 'Invalid number', 'Invalid number', 'Invalid number', 'Invalid number', 'Invalid number']
```

The logical error occurs here, where the expected output should be like this:

```
[6282123321123, 6282321123321, 6282456654456, 6282789987789, 'Invalid number', 6282145451145]
```

Where is the location of that logical error?

Comment: Please take some time to learn [how to debug python code](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+debug+python+code) or [search: debug python on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=debug+python)

Answer (score 0):

It has lot many use cases missing. Ideally it should be as below:

```
def clean_phone_number(phone_lists):
    phone_clean = []

    for phone in phone_lists:
        # Remove all non-digit characters
        cleaned_number = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, phone))

        # Check if the cleaned number starts with '62' and has 11 digits
        if len(cleaned_number) == 11 and not cleaned_number.startswith('62'):
            phone_clean.append(int('62' + cleaned_number))  # Convert to integer and add '62' prefix
        elif len(cleaned_number)==12 and cleaned_number.startswith('0'):
            phone_clean.append(int('62' + cleaned_number[-11:]))
        elif len(cleaned_number) >11 and len(cleaned_number)<14 and cleaned_number.startswith('62'):
            phone_clean.append(int(cleaned_number))
        else:
            phone_clean.append('Invalid number')

    return phone_clean


phone_lists = [
    '82123321123',
    '082321123321',
    '+6282-456-654-456',
    '+62 82 789 987 789',
    '14045',
    '82145-451-145'
]

phone_clean = clean_phone_number(phone_lists)
print(phone_clean)
```

Comment: No!! It will be checked under elif len(cleaned_number) >11 and len(cleaned_number)<14 and cleaned_number.startswith('62'):